# Is there any reason not to remove checks for the Pentium FDIV bug?

Tags: x86, vb6, compiler-optimization, cpu-architecture

See the last checkbox which appears in the VB6 IDE from Project Properties / Compile / Advanced Optimizations:

[image]

This was relevant on buggy hardware of ~ 25 years ago ([1994?](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pentium_FDIV_bug)) but I have a hard time imagining that any current CPUs would still have this problem.

However I am not certain if there are any desirable side-effects of this check that might mean its worth leaving in place? Or undesirable effects of removal?

I see this has been addressed for Delphi, but I can't find anything for VB6.

- ["Pentium-safe FDIV" ... in year 2014?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24101125/pentium-safe-fdiv-in-year-2014)
- [Delphi 6 Compiler Options (Pentium-safe FDIV)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3681244/delphi-6-compiler-options-pentium-safe-fdiv)

From those Q's I get the impression that it is no longer a real concern for Delphi.

---

**Summary of what this was for:**

> Removing Safe Pentium FDIV Checks
>
> This is yet another floating-point
> optimization. Some of Intel’s early Pentium chips had a bug that
> affected certain floating-point division calculations. By default,
> VB’s mathematical routines guard against the Pentium bug, but doing
> the math in VB code is slower than letting the processor chip do it
> for you. If you are confident that your programs won’t run on a
> machine with the Pentium FDIV bug, you may want to activate this
> optimization.

([ref1](https://www.freetutes.com/learn-vb6-advanced/lesson20/p17.html))

---

And **some code to check for the bad hardware**, which illustrates the problem itself:

> ```
> ' return True if the CPU suffers from the FDIV bug
>
> Function IsBuggedPentium() As Boolean
>     IsBuggedPentium = ((1 / 3221224323) * 3221224323) <> 1 
> End Function
> ```
>
> Note that this code always returns False in a VB application that runs
> as p-code or compiled with the standard compilation options. To
> actually detect the bug, you must execute this function in an
> application compiled with the "Remove Safe Pentium(tm) FDIV Checks",
> in the Project Properties - Advanced Optimizations dialog box.

([ref2](http://www.devx.com/vb2themax/Tip/18559))

Comment: Removing the checks can improve performance. Modern processors don't have that FDIV bug just those earlier pentiums. So unless you know you are going to be on an ancient pentium processor there will be no risk. If your application may be run on such old processors then you would have to consider it.

Comment: *any undesirable side-effects of this check that might mean its worth leaving in place?* - perhaps you meant to say *desirable* side effects of the check?  The obvious *un*desirable side-effect is lower performance.  Presumably the numerical results are identical.

Comment: @PeterCordes yes, you read it the way I meant it. thanks

Comment: Remove the check and then remove the Pentium from the list of supported processors. Then charge your customers and additional 0.0001$ to compensate for the loss of the 2 potential buyers that are still using a Pentium in 2020 :)